# Adding bold text to variable

Tags: javascript

I am just beginning with JavaScript and what I am trying to achieve now is to add bold style to a variable result. The code that I am refering to is the following:

```
if(isNumeric(n)) { 
    document.write("The square root of " + n + " is " + answer); 
} 
else { 
    alert('This is not a number!');
}
```

I want to make the variable `answer` to appear in bold and the result to look like this:

**Example:** The square root of 4 is **2**

*Thank you all in advance!*

Comment: Please include what you have tried already to make it bold.  Stack Overflow isn't just for "give me the answer" its to try and learn from mistakes (your own and others').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a matter of adding some HTML ?

```
if(isNumeric(n)) { 
    document.write("The square root of " + n + " is <strong>" + answer + "</strong>"); 
} else { 
    alert('This is not a number!');
}
```

This is fine for testing, but in production you wouldn't really use `document.write`, and preferably you'd use an external stylesheet and a wrapper element to make parts of the text bold.

Comment: *cough* How about `String(answer).bold()` instead? (I would never suggest doing that, I just find it funny. I should probably delete this comment before people are doing that...).

Comment: @FelixKling - Oh, that's old school, but then again so is using tags and `document.write`. Had completely forgotten you could actually do that, and it wraps the string in `<b>` tags

Comment: I just remembered that it exists. I think that's my least favorite feature in JS :D

Comment: Seconded for mentioning "in production you wouldn't really use `document.write`"

Comment: Thank you all and especially **adeneo**! It seems like I was pretty close but forgot the `+` operator in front of the closing tag :[ Thank again!

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for pointing this... I don't suppose it would be possible to do something like 'String(answer).bold().underline()' though, would it? 